# UiTabBar hijack click

Tags: iphone, click, uitabbar

I have a UITabBar and on the last tab, visually 5th, i want to make it logout the user amd not show a view.  I then want the 1st tabbar item to be selected afyer logout is successful. Has anyone seen how to do this?

Tia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

The UITabBarControllerDelegate has a method:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Check this for the fifth item and return NO, then after the process of logging out is complete, set the tab to 1 programatically.

```
[tabBar setSelectedItem:firstController];
```

Comment: Note, however, that this could very well be considered a confusing user interface. Users expect a tab bar tab to load a view, not necessarily to perform some functionality. Consider having a Log Out button somewhere else in the UI, especially in the relevant view (or a toolbar).